# Computing holonomy in non-abelian context

Tags: differential-geometry

Let :

- $G$ be a finite dimensional smooth Lie group,
- $P \to B$ be a trivial principal $G$-bundle over a smooth manifold $B$ ($G$ acting on the right of $P$),
- $A$ be a connection 1-form over $P$,
- $s$ be smooth a global section of $P$.

If $G$ is abelian, the holonomy of $A$ along a smooth loop $\gamma : S^1 \to B$ can be calculated explicitly :
$$
\mathrm{Hol}_A(\gamma) = \exp \left(-\int_{S^1}\gamma^*s^*A\right)
$$
*Question :* if $G$ is non-abelian, is this formula still valid ? If not, how to compute explicitly the holonomy of $A$ along a given loop $\gamma$ ?

---

*Remark :* If $G$ is a matrix group, this problem amounts to explicit the value of $g_0^{-1} g_1$ where $g_t : [0,1]\to G$ is a curve in $G$ satisfying the ODE
$$
\dot{g}_tg_t^{-1} = f_t
$$
where :

- $g_0 \in G$ is fixed
- $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathrm{Lie}(G) := T_e G$
- $f:[0,1]\to\mathfrak{g}$ is defined by $f_t:= -(\gamma^*s^*A)|_t(\partial_t)$ and satisties $f_0=f_1$ (so $f_t$ is a loop in $\mathfrak{g}$).

Comment: I am curious. Do you have a reference for the holonomy formula?

Comment: @EduardoLonga I don't have a reference in front of me. But, finding the ODE is pretty direct : a horizontal lift of $\gamma$ to $P$ can be written as $\tilde{\gamma}_t = s(\gamma_t)\cdot g_t$ where $g_t$ is a path in $G$ (here $G$ acts on the right of $P$). Now differentiate $\tilde{\gamma}$ by $t$, use Leibniz rule, evaluate $A$ on it (+ remember $\tilde{\gamma}$ is horizontal) and the ODE appears. Now, in the abelian case the holonomy equation follows from the ODE. But in the non-abelian case I'm stuck because $\exp(\xi_1+\xi_2)\ne \exp(\xi_1)\exp(\xi_2)$ for $\xi_1,\xi_2 \in \mathfrak{g}$.